# git hub "could not read from remote repository" error

Tags: git

I attempted to use git push, and got an error "fatal:could not read from remote repository".

I found out that there was an issue with the access for the public key being denied.  From the suggested solutions, i have tried various things like 
"eval $(ssh-agent)" but i am still hitting a wall.Not sure where to go from here.

my "remote.origin.url" and "remote.origin.fetch" have been defined, as seen when i run "git config --list"

I was previously able to use git push and connect to git hub but now i am unable to do so.

Thanks.

**Update**

```
$ git remote -v 
origin git@github.com:yuanic/datasciencecoursera.git (fetch) 
origin git@github.com:yuanic/datasciencecoursera.git (push)
origini git@github.com:yuanic/datasciencecoursera.git (fetch) 
origini git@github.com:yuanic/datasciencecoursera.git (push)
```

*(i actually have no idea how "origini" came up. it was likely a typing error but i cannot seem to remove them from git )*

`ssh git@github.com` results in permission denied(publickey).

Comment: You will need to provide us with actual information before we can answer this question.  What does the output of `git remote -v` look like?  Is your *private* key `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, or something else? Can you successfully run `ssh git@github.com`?

Comment: (Generally, update your question rather than including command output in comments.)  It looks like you are using the wrong private key for your github account.  Is ~/.ssh/id_rsa  the *private* key corresponding to the *public* key you have configured in github?